# Video streaming from mobile to laptop to web

Tags: video, video-streaming

I have to work with a colleague to create a streaming application that needs 2-4 phones, a laptop and a browser.
He works on the mobile app and he has to record video and send it directly to me (the laptop) - like a video stream (let's call it A). I have to receive all the streams from all 2-4 phones (A1, A2, A3 and A4) and display them in a window where an operator will chose how the final stream (B) will look like by choosing from which phone will take the video. B will be shown in a browser page (still have to decide this).

Basically, I have to accept 2-4 phones to connect to me, then I have to intercept the video stream from them and then by selecting from A1 to A4, B will have to display my selection and then redirecting it to a web browser page. This is also known as a video switcher or multicam software switcher.

This is what my app will look like:
A1 - A4 will show what phones are sending and by clicking them will change what stream will display B.

```
       _________
[A1]  |         |
[A2]  |         |
[A3]  |    B    |
[A4]  |_________|
```

Can you recommend me a programming language, a plugin, libraries that will help me achieve my goal? Also what is the most likely format in which I will receive the video from mobile.

Note: all I found by now is that the audio and video are encoded separately and then assembled as MP4/FLV/WebM/ASF/ISMA and that video and audio are transported over a network using RTSP/RTP/HTTP Live Streaming (or at least these are recommended).

P.S. I already reached the Software Recommendation forum, but there aren't so many active users.

Danke!

Comment: have you looked at something like Livestream, vMix, or OBS?

Comment: I checked them out, even Switcher studio, I sent an email to WOWZA ( i understood they have  a sdk that might help) but I found that JavaCV could help my cause. But I have to read documentation first. Also, any info about how can I implement it using JavaCV is much appreciated.